# ¿Existe algun tipo de variable que se pueda usar en diferentes capas de un proyecto de asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, variables, asp.net-core

Tengo un proyecto web de asp.net en el que tengo 3 capas.
1- Capa de datos (donde manejo la base de datos).
2- Capa de negocios (donde hago el acceso a la capa de datos).
3- Capa de presentación (el sitio web, donde tengo la interfaz del usuario).

En el LogIn que tengo en la capa de presentación yo armo el `ConnectionString` según el cliente que se está logueando (porque cada uno maneja una base de datos diferente). Necesito poder guardar en una variable ese `ConnectionString` y poder usar esa variable en la capa de datos.

¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo? Porque logicamente las variables `Session` no puedo usarlas en otra capa que no sea la de presentación.
Lo que quiero evitar es tener que armar un constructor en cada clase que haga de la capa de negocios y pasarle la variable y luego tener que hacer lo mismo en la capa de datos. Lo ideal sería tener una "variable compartida" entre las 3 capas.

Desde ya muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que estuve viendo en internet, no hay forma de compartir una variable entre los 3 proyectos por un tema de seguridad.
Lo que hay que hacer es un constructor en cada clase de la capa de negocios y ahí pasar como parámetro la cadena de conexión, luego en la capa de datos hacer lo mismo. De esta manera se comparte (por así decirlo) la cadena creada.

Lo más fácil es usar `ConfigurationManager` y guardar cada cadena de conexión en el `Web.config`, pero por una cuestión de seguridad no queremos guardarlas ahí, ya que si de alguna manera se accede al `Web.config` se podrían ver las credenciales de la BD.

Answer (score 0):

No sé si lo que quieres es que sea para cada usuario que tengas en tu BD o por perfil.
Probablemente si no son muchas cadenas de conexión y las guardas en tu Web.config podrías usar ConfigurationManager.

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("NombreVariable").ConnectionString
```

Esta se encuentra en System.Configuration.

Espero te sea de ayuda.

Comment: No me sirve tenerlo en el Web.Config, por eso tengo todas las conexiones en una base de datos

Answer (score 0):

Lo mejor es que en tu capa de negocios uses un ContextBase implementando una Interfase para que no te puedan robar acceso a tu base de datos en la web hay mucha información de como crear un ContextBase.cs te dejo un ejemplo

```
using domain.Entities;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Infraestructure.Config
{
     public class ContextBase : DbContext
     {
          public ContextBase(DbContextOptions<ContextBase> options) : base(options)
          {

          }

          //Configuracion de DBSet
          public DbSet<proveedor> proveedor { get; set; }
          public DbSet<permisosoperacionesview> permisos { get; set; }

          protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
          {
               modelBuilder
                   .Entity<permisosoperacionesview>(pv =>
                   {
                        pv.HasNoKey();
                        pv.ToView("rol_permisos_operaciones_view");
                        pv.Property(v => v.custumer).HasColumnName("customer");
                        pv.Property(v => v.userID).HasColumnName("userID");
                        pv.Property(v => v.nombre).HasColumnName("nombre");
                        pv.Property(v => v.apellido).HasColumnName("apellido");
                        pv.Property(v => v.rolID).HasColumnName("rolID");
                        pv.Property(v => v.rol).HasColumnName("rol");
                        pv.Property(v => v.permisoID).HasColumnName("permisoID");
                        pv.Property(v => v.passtaskID).HasColumnName("passtaskID");
                        pv.Property(v => v.tarea).HasColumnName("tarea");
                        pv.Property(v => v.ruta).HasColumnName("ruta");
                        pv.Property(v => v.descripcion).HasColumnName("descripcion");
                   });
          }

          protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
          {
               if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
               {
                    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(ConnectionStringConfig());
               }
          }

          private string ConnectionStringConfig()
          {
               string strConn = "Data Source=Nombre-servidor;Initial Catalog=Anser;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=***********";

               return strConn;
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte, pero en este caso no vamos a usar EntityFramework, por lo que no me sirve esta solucion.

Comment: Entiendo si encuentro algo por la web te lo comparto espero resuelvas el problema. Saludos